# .NET Fast Persistent Queue

Tags: .net, queue

I am looking for a queue system where multiple different subscribers can pull items off a centralized queue. The messages will be very lightweight, but i need something that is persistent and very fast as the volume of messages will be large. MSMQ is a little heavy and i am looking for something light. Suggestions?

Comment: a database table (with appropriate locking mechanisms)?

Comment: We are currently using a database table. But, its fairly slow. I need something with a little more throughput and hopefully functionality...

Comment: "But, its fairly slow. " - it shouldn't be. what do you term slow?

Comment: How about a ConcurrentQueue that you store in memory and persist to the database periodically? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Comment: Slow in a sense that the process has to constantly open a connection to SQL and update the queue. It seems like something local would be much faster. I suppose i could use some type of embedded DB, but it also seems that might be heavy just for a work queue.

Answer (score 3):

There is a really nice project on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/DotNetMQ.aspx). That is lightweight alternative to MSMQ.
You can use persistence storage of your own choice, by default it uses Sqlite. 
This is really good.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question here is do you "need" persistance?  If you need protection from duplicates, multiple clients and persistence then you will be all but forced to pursue a locking scheme for your queue manager, which will cost you in performance.  Persistance itself will hurt you unless you put the queue storage on a high speed file share.

If you can rearchitect your app to survive a queue crash (keep a feed at the server, or have a request / response architecture for messages) then you can get around the need for persistance.  If you do that then you will find that your queue manager runs exclusively in memory and will be extremely fast.

Comment: Interesting. The app that we are building is very processor intensive, i was envisioning a scenario where one server acts as the sort of broker for farming out tasks to the another "processing" servers. In this scenario, i just need the queue on the broker to be resilient. Do you have an point of reference or examples with guidelines for building something like this?